# filtering an axios response

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, request

I made an axios request and Im receiving a large amount of data back and Im not sure how to filter it.

This is my code

```
await axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
const authToken = response
console.log(authToken)  
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

This is just a small part of the response

```
<form class="edit_checkout" action="/942252/checkouts/536693bdcfc6f7344d1a5b500b546824" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="hFK7eHqqzlwcmpu2o3eeqVsqiNzruv8w0IPsDUQdDExwN-cdMlEsEWqYGbabkMvUf_rs_FnmmzY6H1MiSdIMOw" />\n' +
    '  <input type="hidden" name="step" value="contact_information" />\n'
```

I want the to locate this part of the response by the form class and I need the string that is associated with the value attribute. How would I do this?

Comment: Just to clarify I need the value that is the very long string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse the response with [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) - then you can use `querySelector` etc

```
await axios(config)
.then(function(response) {
    const parser = new DOMParser;
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/html");
    const input = doc.querySelector('form.edit_checkout input[name="authenticity_token"]');
    const value = input.value;
    console.log(value);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Although, since you're using `await` ...

```
const response = await axios(config);
const parser = new DOMParser;
const doc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/html");
const input = doc.querySelector('form.edit_checkout input[name="authenticity_token"]');
const value = input.value;
console.log(value);
```

in a try/catch is better code

By the way, depending on the HTML, the `querySelector` could be just

```
doc.querySelector('[name="authenticity_token"]');
```

I put as much as I can in a selector as "self documentation"